# HTML tags appear as <tags> and doesn't do apply CSS on it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an  tag and I'm trying to apply some CSS when I type # or @ into it but the outputs returns a `<span class="hightlight>`

What I'm trying to do is to apply the `<span class="hightlight">` style and make the HTML tag dissapear

So the expected output should have CSS styling in it and also in the input tag

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
            var hashtags = false;
            var at = false;
            $(document).on('keydown', '.hashtag', function(e) {        
                arrow = {
                    hashtag: 51,
                    at: 48,
                    space: 32
                };
                var input_field = $(this);
                switch (e.which) {
                    case arrow.hashtag:
                    input_field.val(input_field.val() + "<span class='highlight'>");
                    hashtags = true;
                    break;
                    case arrow.at:
                    input_field.val(input_field.val() + "<span class='highlight'>");
                    at = true;
                    break;
                    case arrow.space:
                    if(hashtags) {
                        input_field.val(input_field.val() + "</span>");
                        hashtags = false;
                    }
                    if(at) {
                        input_field.val(input_field.val() + "</span>");
                        at = false;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            });
        });
```

HTML/CSS:

```
<input type="text" class="hashtag" placeholder="#...">
<style>
  .highlight {
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>
```

So, what I'm trying to do is to get CSS styling into the input tag

Comment: `<input type="text">` can only contain plain text. Not HTML.

Comment: @Turnip `<input>` is an [empty element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element), it does not contain anything at all.

Comment: Some website use the two layers tricks. They put a a div or span under an input/ textarea. The text color of the input will be transparent and some javascript code will refresh the span/div under it with HTML and formatting.

Comment: @TiiJ7 You know what I mean. `value` :p